queryClient.refetchQueries() not working when previous mutation failed due to api error
The "duplicateJob" mutation is working fine when previous api call is 200/ok, even when I tried to call the deleteMutation and then call the duplicateMutation again is still working (queryClient.refetchQueries() works),
But when I tried to call "deleteMutation" and if its failed then I tried to call "duplicateMutation" again, duplicateMutation works and its onSuccess was called but the "queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [QUERY_TAG_JOBS] })" not working
I noticed also: when i tried to delete via mutate and if there is error from api, the context of my query tag was gone when i checked in my dev tools. So when i tried to mutate(POST) again it succeed but the queryClient.refetchQueries() not working.
Upon Page Reload:

When I delete a specific job that will trigger error, I noticed that the query tag ["jobs"] is gone

etc:



im expecting that jobs api will refetch
